# Gnome Left Menu Gone

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

Months ago I changed kernels temporarily from 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 to 5.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 then I reverted back to 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 within a few hours.  Once I loaded up 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 I ended up losing the Super Key feature and "Left menu".  I am using CentOS7 and now have to click the "Applications" and select tools that way.

What I realized is  3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 is using Gnome 3.28.2. So Kernel 5.8.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 likely had a newer Gnome version which created a conflict.

I feel like there is a repair command I can run or something to get the left menu bar and "Windows" search key back.

Any ideas how to get it back?  This is a total pita.

Answer (score 0):

I guess when I changed kernels it changed to GNOME classic.  So I logged out, clicked the gear icon then selected Gnome and vioala!